# Replicar/Copiar elementos de várias tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho a seguinte situação: O utilizador tem definido um estabelecimento, onde tem preenchidos dados em duas tabelas, e pretende replicar/copiar os dados todos iguais, mudando apenas o id do estabelecimento. Tenho as tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela AcidezImpurezaHumidade_tbl ou AIH como tenho no projecto, recebe como chave estrangeira os ServicosID da tabela Servicos.

Na minha função para replicar/copiar os dados, recebo um inteiro que contém o id do estabelecimento (idServicoIDSelected) que vou copiar e uma lista com os id's dos estabelecimentos (listaEstab) para onde copiar:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult CriarCopiarEstab(List<int> listaEstab, int idServicoIDSelected, string serie, int numDoc)
    {
        try
        {
            var dados = db.DadosComerciais.Where(d => d.Serie == serie && d.NumDoc == numDoc).FirstOrDefault();
            var servico = db.Servicos.Find(idServicoIDSelected);
            var aih = db.AIH.Where(a => a.ServicosID == servico.ServicosID).ToList();
            foreach (var item in listaEstab)
            {
                var newServico = new Servicos();
                newServico = servico;
                newServico.DadosComerciais = db.DadosComerciais.Find(serie, numDoc);

                db.Servicos.Add(newServico);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var newAih = new List<AIH>();
                foreach (var item2 in aih)
                {
                    var newElementoAih = new AIH();
                    newElementoAih.AcidezDesconto = item2.AcidezDesconto;
                    newElementoAih.AcidezMax = item2.AcidezMax;
                    newElementoAih.AcidezTaxaExtraEur = item2.AcidezTaxaExtraEur;
                    //newElementoAih = item2; //TAMBEM JÁ EXPERIMENTEI ASSIM
                    db.AIH.Add(newElementoAih);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Onde tenho o problema?** 
Não estou a conseguir replicar os dados, ir buscar o `servicosID` correspondente para inserir na tabela AIH. Se replicar apenas a tabela dos Servicos funciona bem, agora se começar a copiar as listas obtenho sempre o erro:

> **InvalidOperationException was caught**
>   The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Comment: Em qual linha exatamente ocorre o erro?

Comment: Logo quando faço `saveChanges()` da tabela serviços

Comment: @CesarMiguel Você conseguiu uma solução para o problema? Você pode postar uma resposta com ele para o pessoal votar (pode até aceitá-la como correta.

Answer (score 1):

Esta definição:

```
var newServico = new Servicos();
newServico = servico;
newServico.DadosComerciais = db.DadosComerciais.Find(serie, numDoc);
```

Está errada. Você está definindo dois objetos do tipo `Servicos` com o mesmo `ServicoID`. O Entity Framework entende que são dois objetos diferentes, mas o SQL Server entende que os objetos são iguais.

Não sei como é seu esquema de banco, mas o código supondo o uso de Identity na coluna `ServicoID` é mais ou menos assim:

```
var newServico = new Servicos();
newServico.NumDocumento = servico.NumDocumento;
newServico.Serie = servico.Serie;
newServico.DadosComerciais = db.DadosComerciais.Find(serie, numDoc);
// Preencha as demais properties manualmente. Não preencha ServicoID

db.Servicos.Add(newServico);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: O estranho é que quando gravo apenas a tabela Serviços ele guarda bem. Mas agora se verificar que há dados na outra tabela, e for percorrer a lista para guardar é que dá erro. Já contornei o problema. Fiz o seguinte: Mando guardar primeiro os dados da tabela serviços a partir do javascript, e depois no fim desses dados estar guardados, mando (também a partir de javascript) guardar a lista de dados na tabela AIH